# counting checkboxes after click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, checkbox

I need to count the number of checkboxes in a form that are 'checked' AFTER being clicked and BEFORE the form is submitted. I have a javascript function that is called when a box is clicked which changes some values in the form dynamically. But it is returning the counts and values which are present at the time the box is clicked.

As my code is now, I have an onClick event handler on a  enclosing the checkbox and label:

```
<div class="part" style="padding-right: 30px" onClick="runThis()">
    <input id="checkbox_2" name="dog" type="checkbox" class='topdog'                              checked='checked' value="2" />
    <label for="checkbox_2">Snoopy (Top Dog)</label>
</div>

...


    function runThis() { 
    var dogsSelected = jQuery("input[name='dog']:checked");
    var numSelected = dogsSelected.length;
    alert("numSelected: " + numSelected);
    }
```

I am sure there is a simple solution or I am approaching this incorrectly.

Any tips/advice are appreciated.

Comment: do you want to ignore the selection of checkbox being clicked?

Comment: `number of checkboxes in a form that are 'checked' AFTER being clicked ` .. this is ambiguous .. Can you explain your problem more clearly

Comment: No, I want the value of the checkbox being clicked to be included in the results

Comment: Thank you for all of your responses, they all had merit, but the issue ended up being in a custom package we were using to handle the event. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If so, you should try to change it to react on mouse up, you should get a different result.

You are probably activating the event before the changes has been made to the dom three.

Edit:

nevermind it says onclick triggers in the question. my bad for not reading.

Try changing it to : onmouseup, i guess that should do the trick:

```
<div class="part" style="padding-right: 30px" onmouseup="runThis()">
<input id="checkbox_2" name="dog" type="checkbox" class='topdog'                              checked='checked' value="2" />
<label for="checkbox_2">Snoopy (Top Dog)</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are there any JavaScript errors? I found that if you take that `runThis()` function out of `$(document).ready` it works properly.

You might also consider removing that `onClick=` attribute in favor of jQuery event handlers:

```
$("input[name='dog']").on('click',function(e) {
    var dogsSelected = $("input[name='dog']:checked");
    var numSelected = dogsSelected.length;
    alert("numSelected: " + numSelected);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/xsWDn/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'change' event:

```
$("input[name='dog']").on('change', runThis);

function runThis() {
    var dogsSelected = jQuery("input[name='dog']:checked");
    var numSelected = dogsSelected.length;
    alert("numSelected: " + numSelected);
}​
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/